# How can I define a radius around a path in a map?

Tags: json, google-maps, geojson

I have a project that requires restricting map data to places within a specified radius of a distinct path. I have the coordinates for the path but I am trying to figure out how to exclusively return results for places within a defined radius of the path.

Here is a link of the defined path (https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z50O4Yim6Hzk.kv9fLqu7MB80) - the thick gray portion being the section of interest.

To be more explicit, I am creating an app that shows users places along a walkable path.